# Windows 10. Alieware Computer. Setup/Uninstall opens and closes constantly

Tags: windows, uninstall, setup

On my taskbar, it appears that my currently selected program, google chrome, gets unselected and something opens with no icon and immediately dissappears, not really a problem,but it makes typing very difficult because it interrupts. Also, a chyme comes on everytime I try to type while the program interrupts which is very annoying. I opened the task manager and a program called "Setup/Uninstall (32 bit)" pops up and dissapears about every 10 seconds, more often than my taskbar shows. It doesn't stay long enough for me to try and end task, sadly. Please help. I can't find any solutions.

Comment: run adwcleaner.exe from bleepcomputer site and post results

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled all the apps I have uninstalled recently, and looked inside my task managers inside the background processes. Setup was there and I clicked on it quickly and ended the task. I believe the app that caused my problem was Bluestacks, an Android emulator.